# Order a set of numbers to maximize adjacent differences

Tags: sorting, mathematical-optimization

Given a set of N numbers `x1`, `x2`, ..., `xN`, how can you find an ordering of them to maximize the minimum absolute difference between adjacent numbers? This is probably an NP hard problem, so any efficient approximate method will do.

Comment: wouldnt just ordering them from lowest to highest or highest to lowest be the best solution? what language are you looking for a solution in? have a look at something like these kinds of sorting :) http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/~hutchins/csci230/sorting.htm

Comment: No, sorted order is worst actually. For numbers 1-5, the ordering 1,3,5,2,4 is better because the minimum difference between any two adjacent numbers is 2.

Comment: ok sorry, i miss interpreted what you meant by 'maximise the minimum' difference. (i would recommend removing the words "the minimum" in your question)

Comment: It's important because I want to optimize in the L-infinity norm rather than anything else (like L2).

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you've defined your data as x_i for i=1, ..., n. We can define binary variables p_{ij} for i=1, ..., n, and j=1, ..., n, which are 1 if number i is in sorted order j and 0 otherwise. Adding a variable e, our optimization model would be something like:

[image: first try]

The constraints with the absolute values ensure that e (our minimum gap) does not exceed the gap between each pair of adjacent elements in our sorted sequence. However, absolute values aren't allowed in linear optimization models, and in general you need to add a binary variable to model an absolute value being greater than or equal to some other value. So let's add binary variable r_j, j=2, ..., n, and replace our problematic constraints:

[image: second try]

Here M is a large number; 2(max(x) - min(x)) should be sufficiently large. Now, we're ready to actually implement this model. You can use any MIP solver; I'll use the `lpSolveAPI` in R because it's free and easily accessible. p_{ij} are stored in variables 1 through n^2; r_j are stored in variables n^2+1 through n^2+n-1; and e is stored in variable n^2+n.

```
x = 1:5
n = length(x)
M = 2*(max(x) - min(x))
library(lpSolveAPI)
mod = make.lp(0, n^2+n)
set.type(mod, 1:(n^2+n-1), "binary")
set.objfn(mod, c(rep(0, n^2+n-1), 1))
lp.control(mod, sense="max")
for (j in 2:n) {
  base.cons <- rep(0, n^2+n)
  base.cons[seq(j-1, by=n, length.out=n)] = x
  base.cons[seq(j, by=n, length.out=n)] = -x
  base.cons[n^2+j-1] = M
  first.cons = base.cons
  first.cons[n^2+n] = -1
  add.constraint(mod, first.cons, ">=", 0)
  second.cons = -base.cons
  second.cons[n^2+n] = -1
  add.constraint(mod, second.cons, ">=", -M)
}

for (j in 1:n) {
  this.cons = rep(0, n^2+n)
  this.cons[seq(j, by=n, length.out=n)] = 1
  add.constraint(mod, this.cons, "=", 1)
}

for (i in 1:n) {
  this.cons = rep(0, n^2+n)
  this.cons[seq((i-1)*n+1, i*n)] = 1
  add.constraint(mod, this.cons, "=", 1) 
}
```

Now we're ready to solve the model:

```
solve(mod)
# [1] 0
get.objective(mod)
# [1] 2
get.variables(mod)
# [1] 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 2
```

And lastly we can extract the sorted list using the x_i and p_{ij} variables:

```
sapply(1:n, function(j) sum(get.variables(mod)[seq(j, by=n, length.out=n)]*x))
# [1] 1 3 5 2 4
```